# How to make a mixture of a certain volume with x/y ratio mass?

Tags: concentration

For example for 1mL to get 3:7 mass ratio sand/water.
I have multiple samples to make with different ratios but the same volume and I can't seem to find an ecuation for this.
Thank you!

Comment: What keeps you from the deriving the formula yourself? For additive volumes scenario like (quartz) sand + water, it is trivial. Total volume is sum of sand and water volume. Volume of each component is then ratio of its mass and density. Keeps masses in desired ratio and involve proportionality constant to reach target volume.

Comment: Because it's more complicated than that. My main issue is I have a mixture of 1mL with 30wt% SiO2 and the rest water; and I can't figure out the weight of SiO2 in this mixture and/or the volume it occupies.

Comment: Where is the complication?

Comment: Well, I don't know the weight of the mixture and of the compounds (SiO2 and water). All I know is that out of 1mL of mixture, there is 30wt% of SiO2. And also the density of the compounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's admit that the mixture contains $\pu{x}$ grams sand, and $\pu{y}$ grams water (and also $\pu{y}$ mL water). x and y are two unknowns. Let's take the density of sand $\pu{2.66 g/mL}$. The total volume of the mixture is : $\pu{V = \frac{x}{2.66 g/ml}  + y = 1.00 mL}$. This is the first equation. The second equation is the mass ratio : $\pu{\frac{x}{x+y} = 0.3}$.

The solution of this system is :  $\pu{x = 0.3681 g}$ sand, and $\pu{y = 0.8615 g}$ water. As the total mass is $\pu{1.2296 g}$, the fraction of sand is $\pu{\frac{0.3681 g}{ 1.2296~g} = 0.300 = 30}$%

If this is of interest, the volume of the sand can be calculated : $\pu{V_{sand} = 0.3681 g/(2.66 g/mL) = 0.1385 mL }$. With $\pu{0.8615 mL}$ water, it makes a total volume $\pu{1.000 mL}$

Answer (score 0):

$$V = m ( \frac {w}{\rho_\mathrm{sand}}+ \frac {1-w}{\rho_\mathrm{water}})$$

$$m = \frac {V}{ \frac {w}{\rho_\mathrm{sand}}+ \frac {1-w}{\rho_\mathrm{water}}}$$

$$m_\mathrm{sand} = \frac {Vw}{ \frac {w}{\rho_\mathrm{sand}}+ \frac {1-w}{\rho_\mathrm{water}}}=\frac{\pu{1 mL} \cdot 0.3}{\frac{0.3}{\pu{2.65 g mL-1}}+\frac{0.7}{\pu{1 g mL-1}}}\approx \pu{0.369 g}$$

$$m_\mathrm{water} = \frac {V(1-w)}{ \frac {w}{\rho_\mathrm{sand}}+ \frac {1-w}{\rho_\mathrm{water}}}=\frac{\pu{1 mL} \cdot 0.7}{\frac{0.3}{\pu{2.65 g mL-1}}+\frac{0.7}{\pu{1 g mL-1}}} \approx \pu{0.861 g} \equiv \pu{0.861 mL}$$

There would be obvious issue with maintaining the desired local mass ratio  within the mixture because of sedimentation, but I suppose the mixture is prepared in-situ from components.

| Quantity | Legend |
| --- | --- |
| V | total volume |
| m | total mass |
| w | mass fraction <0..1> of sand |
| $\rho$ | density. Density of water is trivial (1 g/mL) unless high accuracy is needed. Knowledge of sand density is mandatory. For pure enough quartz sand it is 2.65 g/mL. |
| mw | sand mass |
| m(1-w) | water mass |